# MS SQL 2005- Rollback Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, rollback

I'm using MS SQL Server 2005 enterprise edition. I executed an update query to get affect a record in a row and a column.

```
update HS_SM_USERACCOUNT 
set ACCOUNTPOLICYTYPE=1  
where EMP_NUMBER='000540' and USERID='03510410@'
```

Earlier the column called `ACCOUNTPOLICYTYPE` is holding value `1` for that particular condition in WHERE clause. Now I want to get the previous state without executing Update Query again.

Will `ROLLBACK` help me? Please help me on this.

Comment: So, you want to set accounttype to 0 or another value that is not 1? You can't do that without executing an UPDATE statement or restoring a backup from before you ran your UPDATE. If you want to do a ROLLBACK you must first have executed a BEGIN TRANSACTION statement.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's changed. If you want to know what it was, restore from backup

Answer (score 0):

Unless you executed the above query within the scope of a TRANSACTION - i.e. within `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT / ROLLBACK TRAN` block, the `ROLLBACK` command is going to be of no use.

There is nothing you can do to get back the state that you updated with the above statement in such a situation except RESTORE an OLD backup of that table data